# joomla article not open?

Tags: joomla

i m facing problem to open a new article in joomla, when i click on link following error display on the page

Homepage is showing:
404 - Component not found

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

1. an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
2. a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
3. a mistyped address
4. you have no access to this page
5. The requested resource was not found.
6. An error has occurred while processing your request.

Please try one of the following pages:

**Link of the page is:**  http://punjabtourism.gov.in/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=86&Itemid=71

when we click **BOQ** the last link of the site next page will show the above error if anybody have solution please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your setting in 'GLobal Configuration' in the first menu in the backend. Go to Search Engine Friendly URL's, check if its on. Check if 'mod-rewrite' is on. If these have been enabled after you created an article, then your links wont work. You need to add the article after enabling these settings to make it work properly.

Your best bet is to re-publish all your articles, the links should work fine then.

Hope this helps.